# Difference between collections.abc.Sequence and typing.Sequence

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-typing, generic-collections

I was reading an article and about collection.abc and typing class in the python standard library and discover both classes have the same features.

I tried both options using the code below and got the same results

```
from collections.abc import Sequence

def average(sequence: Sequence):
    return sum(sequence) / len(sequence)

print(average([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]))  # result is 3.0

from typing import Sequence

def average(sequence: Sequence):
    return sum(sequence) / len(sequence)

print(average([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])) # result is 3.0
```

Under what condition will collection.abc become a better option to typing. Are there benefits of using one over the other?

Comment: In older versions of python, `typing.Sequence` is a generic version of `collections.abc.Sequence`, used for typing. In recent versions, both are generic and `typing.Sequence` is essentially deprecated

Comment: here is how `Sequence` is defined in `typing`: `Sequence = _alias(collections.abc.Sequence, 1)`. So it is the same thing.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Good on you for using type annotations! As the documentations says, if you are on Python `3.9+`, you should most likely never use [`typing.Sequence`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Sequence) due to its deprecation. Since the introduction of [generic alias types](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#types-genericalias) in `3.9` the [`collections.abc`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections-abstract-base-classes) classes all support subscripting and should be recognized correctly by static type checkers of all flavors.

So the benefit of using `collections.abc.T` over `typing.T` is mainly that the latter is deprecated and should not be used.

As mentioned by jsbueno in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75285779/19770795), annotations will never have runtime implications either way, unless of course they are explicitly picked up by a piece of code. They are just an essential part of good coding style. But your function would still work, i.e. your script would execute without error, even if you annotated your function with something absurd like `def average(sequence: 4%3): ...`.

---

Proper annotations are still extremely valuable. Thus, I would recommend you get used to some of the best practices as soon as possible. (A more-or-less strict static type checker like [mypy](/questions/tagged/mypy) is very helpful for that.) For one thing, when you are using **generic** types like `Sequence`, you should *always* provide the appropriate type arguments. Those may be [type variables](https://peps.python.org/pep-0483/#type-variables), if your function is also generic or they may be concrete types, but you should always include them.

In your case, assuming you expect the contents of your `sequence` to be something that can be added with the same type and divided by an integer, you might want to e.g. annotate it as `Sequence[float]`. (In the Python type system, `float` is considered a supertype of `int`, even though there is no nominal inheritance.)

Another recommendation is to try and be as **broad** as possible in the parameter types. <s>(This echoes the Python paradigm of dynamic typing.)</s> The idea is that you just specify that the object you expect must be able to *"quack"*, but you don't say it must be a duck.

In your example, since you are reliant on the argument being compatible with [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) as well as with [`len`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#len), you should consider what types *those* functions expect. The `len` function is simple, since it basically just calls the `__len__` method of the object you pass to it. The `sum` function is more nuanced, but in your case the relevant part is that it expects an [**iterable**](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterable) of elements that can be added (e.g. `float`).

If you take a look at the [collections ABCs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections-abstract-base-classes), you'll notice that `Sequence` actually offers much more than you need, being that it is a reversible collection. A `Collection` is the broadest built-in type that fulfills your requirements because it has `__iter__` (from `Iterable`) and `__len__` (from `Sized`). So you could do this instead:

```py
from collections.abc import Collection


def average(numbers: Collection[float]) -> float:
    return sum(numbers) / len(numbers)
```

(By the way, the parameter name should not reflect its type.)

Lastly, if you wanted to go all out and be as broad as possible, you could define your own [**protocol**](https://peps.python.org/pep-0544/) that is even broader than `Collection` (by getting rid of the `Container` inheritance):

```py
from collections.abc import Iterable, Sized
from typing import Protocol, TypeVar


T = TypeVar("T", covariant=True)


class SizedIterable(Sized, Iterable[T], Protocol[T]):
    ...  # Literal ellipsis, not a placeholder


def average(numbers: SizedIterable[float]) -> float:
    return sum(numbers) / len(numbers)
```

This has the advantage of supporting very broad structural subtyping, but is most likely overkill.

(For the basics of Python typing, [PEP 483](https://peps.python.org/pep-0483/) and [PEP 484](https://peps.python.org/pep-0484/) are a must-read.)

Comment: "They are just an essential part of good coding style"  -could you share some proofs for this claim? Personally, I still stay with PEP484 authors, who "[...] have no desire to ever make type hints mandatory, even by convention", and I work on some untyped codebases without feeling like "how can I live without annotations".

Comment: @SUTerliakov Hard to provide _proof_ for that. While expressed in terms of a statement of fact, that is of course just my opinion. Something like "style" is such an elusive metric that I doubt we can reach something like "final consensus". I personally can not imagine a situation, when omitting type annotations would be a _good_ idea (or better than including them), aside from literally throwing together a one-time script for some ad-hoc action. But that is probably a discussion for another place.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, in your code you need **neither** of those:

Typing with annotations, which is what you are doing with your imported `Sequence`s class is an *optional* feature, meant for (1) quick documentation; (2) checking of the code *before* it is run by static code analysers such as Mypy.

The fact is that some IDEs use the result of static checking by default in their recomented configurations, and they can make it look like code without annotations is "faulty": it is not - this is an *optional* feature.

As long as the *object* you pass into your function respect some of the Sequence interface it will need, it will work (it needs `__len__` and `__getitem__` as is)

Just run your code without annotations and see it work:

```
def average(myvariable):
    return sum(myvariable) / len(myvariable)
```

That said, here is what is happening: `list`  is "the sequence" by excellence in Python, and implements everything a sequence needs.

`typing.Sequence` is just *an indicator* for the static-checker tools that the data marked with it should respect the Sequence protocol, and does nothing at run time. You can't instantiate it. You can inherit from it (probably) but just to specialize other *markers* for typing, not for *anything* that will have any effect during actual program execution.

On the other hand `collections.abc.Sequence` predates the optional typing recomendations in PEP 484: it works as both a "virtual super class" which can indicate everything that works as a sequence in runtime (through the use of `isinstance`) (*). *AND* it can be used as a solid *base* class to implement fully functional cusotm Sequence classes of your own: just inherit from `collections.abc.Sequence` and implement functional `__getitem__` and `__len__` methods as indicated in the docs here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html  (that is for read only sequences - for mutable sequences, check `collections.abc.MutableSequence`, of course).

(*) for your custom sequence implementation to be recognized as a Sequence proper it has to be "registered" in *runtime* with a call to `collections.abc.Sequence.register`. However, AFAIK, most tools for static type checking do not recognize this, and will error in their static analysis)

Comment: Thanks @jsbueno  I'm aware it will run without annotations. i'm enrolled to a bootcamp and learning about type annotation, hence the reason for the initial question.

Comment: yes - I completed the answer with the actual differences between both `Sequence`s now.